# Flutter loads old version of app every time I restart the app

Tags: android, flutter

Every time I run the flutter app from IntelliJ, it loads an old outdated version of the app from days ago. The new version of the app is only loaded after a hot reload and even then, if I restart the app, the old version is loaded again.
I there any way I can fix this issue? It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a bug (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16604) because Flutter should better recognize when rebuilding is required, 
but running

```
flutter clean
```

should fix it in the meantime

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer. I keep having this issue. Even after doing a "Flutter clean" and manually deleting my build directory. After I do that i get 1 good build. But after that every reinstall of the app is that version without the changes I made in the meantime. Also I only have this on 1 pc. My other development machine does not have this problem. Could this be a permission problem? Project is stored in "My documents". To get my newest version I need to build the app and do a full-restart of the app to get my current code running

Comment: @KevinWalter I wasn't able to get any more insight as that `flutter clean` fixes it if modifications are not taking effect. `flutter clean` is supposed to delete the `build` directory, so deleting the build directory seems redundant. Besides that I have no idea what could cause your issue.

Comment: I ran into this issue on VSCode. I experienced the problems you experienced on both emulators (iOS and Android), but it worked fine on physical devices. Restarting/reloading the emulators didn't fix it, but restarting VSCode did.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar behavior and Flutter clean does not resolve the problem.  I find myself deleting / recreating the android emulator as a workaround, but this isn't an option for the iOS emulator.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for sharing. I've been experiencing this issue and it's really disturbing.

Comment: is this a cache problem ?

Comment: @Sachin a problem with artifacts in `my_flutter_project/build` directory not being invalidated when they should. And yes, the build directory is kind of a cache.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i am a android user and when I install my flutter app in real device I am not able to locate my app under    ' android/data/ '  where all the installed app resides in android. Will you pls tell me where I can find my app except home ??

Comment: I don't know which directories the application files are installed to, but for me an `/android/data/com.mydomain.myapp`directory is created, but it only contains an empty `cache` and `files/pictures` directory.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Easy way to do it using Android Studio as shown in snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how this bug hasn't been resolved by now.

But for any one also struggling with this (using visual studio code), who already tried "flutter clean", the only thing that works for me is clicking on "restart" every time I start debugging.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes restart doesn't work specially when you encountered an error.