# All hot restart/reload updates are lost when ADB connection is lost

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

This question is a follow up to [Flutter loads old version of app every time I restart the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752745/flutter-loads-old-version-of-app-every-time-i-restart-the-app)  and the related [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16604) which seemingly has been closed.

In order to avoid  loading an old outdated version of the app from days ago, we need to run `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. `flutter run`

But sometimes the ADB connection gets lost ( I use WiFi ADB). Therefore, when I close then re open the app, it loads the old version from days ago because I did not even have time to run `flutter clean` and rebuild since this is an unexpected loss of ADB connection.

So is there a way to always have flutter persist the last hot changes every time without having to rebuild the app?

Comment: I think when we close the app the connection is lost and we have to run it again . I was experiencing this from 5 months. But you can achieve it by hot restart.  Its similar to re-opening the app. But to see Splash animations i think you have to re-open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to persist the change, `flutter clean` is necessary.

However, it is possible to rebuild the using `flutter build apk --debug` whether the device is connected or not. This will save a lot of time by running it during your development and let it build. When you restart, the app will using this cached apk. It won't be rebuilt from scratch again

Answer (score 0):

There's no solution to that. You have to rebuild the App again after the connection is lost because in flutter there is state which is lost on ADB Connection lost I guess.

And there's nothing mention in the [Official Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload) as well.